# yii2: select data from mongodb and compare with datatype array

Tags: yii, yii2, mongodb-query

I am trying to make a query that compares with array field in table (`vendor`).
I create  following query using Yii2 but it returns empty records.

```
    $id = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('catid');

    $query = new Query;

    $query->select([])
        ->from('vendor')
        ->where(['category' => $id]);

     $rows = $query->all();

    return json_encode($rows);
```

I used mongodb. Here is my table `vendor`.
This is a record from the `vendor` table.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5583f354d88488081b8b4567"),
"address" : "Parle point",
"category" : [ 
    "55a4db79d884888310a7c07e", 
    "55a4ca94d88488320fa7c07e", 
    "55a4e2bfd884888310a7c080"
],
"city" : "Surat",
"country" : "India",
"created_at" : "",
"description" : "Cat Description",
"email" : "test12@test.com",
"firstName" : "vendor1",
"is_visible" : "Visible",
"lastName" : "test",
"logo" : "Image",
"phoneNumber" : "686986979",
"pincode" : "395007",
"state" : "Gujarat",
"updated_at" : NumberLong(1436942895),
"url" : "test,com"
}
```

Why is my select query not returning any records? Remember comparison field has an `array` datatype.

Comment: `$query->select([])`
Why You set to select empty array?

Comment: it means i want all the columns of vendor table.

Comment: You should post what `$query->createCommand()->rawSql` prints out.